# Testing custom views with Robolectric: Width and height are always 0

Tags: android, robolectric

I have build a custom View (DrawView) for a drawing app. It depends heavily on a real width and height for internal bitmaps. When I try to test it with Robolectric 2.2, the view has a length and width of 0 which crashes my internal logic. How can I mock a real screen size? I use a simple LinearLayout with the DrawView as the only element in it to test. Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawViewLayout">
    <net.thoster.scribmasterlib.DrawView
        android:id="@+id/drawView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my Unit Test:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class DrawViewTest {
  Activity activity;
  DrawView drawView;
  LinearLayout layout;

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {

    ActivityController<Activity> activityController = Robolectric.buildActivity(Activity.class).create().start().resume()
        .visible();

    Activity activity = activityController.get();

    layout = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.test, null);
    drawView = (DrawView) layout.findViewById(R.id.drawView);

  }

  @Test
  public void testFloodFill() throws Exception {
    System.out.println(drawView.getWidth());
    drawView.floodFill(new Point(1, 1), Color.BLACK, FloodFillMode.PIXEL);
    Bitmap b = drawView.getDrawingAsNewBitmap();
    int pixel = b.getPixel(2, 2);
    assertEquals(pixel, Color.BLACK);

  }

}
```

Comment: You are trying to get a reference to width and height before they are drawn. First perform a measure and then call getMeasuredHeight/Width

Comment: Sorry, that is not working, either. I tried it this way in the setUp-Method:

    drawView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY,View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

System.out.println(drawView.getMeasuredHeight());

System.out.println(drawView.getMeasuredWidth());

Width and height are still 0.

Comment: The problem here is not that I don't get the height or width of a view in Android. It just doesn't work properly in combination with Robolectric.

Comment: @StefanOstermann Did you find a work around at all? Looking into using Mockito currently but still unsure.

Comment: Eventually I gave up...

Answer (score 3):

As erd points out at https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/819 ...

> Robolectric isn't trying to emulate Android - just fake enough of it so you can write reasonable unit tests.  It doesn't surprise me that views don't have a width or height, since we're not doing anything that would cause a layout pass to happen.

Please see the bug for potential work arounds.